# Xcode 7.3: Can't import MetalKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, metal

I'm trying to do some work with MetalKit. I've created a brand new project based on the Game template with Metal selected as the game technology. For some reason, though, Xcode 7.3 won't recognize MetalKit as a valid module. At the top of `GameViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import Metal
import MetalKit
```

The import statement for MetalKit is flagged with the error `No such module 'MetalKit'` I've checked and the MetalKit.framework definitely exists in the frameworks folder along with Metal and all the others.

This also fails if I base the project on Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MetalKit` isn't available as part of the iOS Simulator SDK.  Building on an actual device and linking the iOS SDK should allow you to link the framework properly.

Comment: It's weird that we're allowed the use of Metal, but not MetalKit.

Comment: You're allowed to link against Metal as a module because there's a stub implementation of the framework in the iOS Simulator SDK, but trying to actually use Metal at runtime doesn't work, as calling `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` returns `nil`.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation warrenm!

Comment: @warrenm Didn't knew Metal was now available in the iOS simulator !

Answer (score 2):

The problem may occur if you are building for iOS Simulator, since MetalKit is not available there. Setting the active scheme to a device should resolve that.